# Install Ubuntu on new HDD

Tags: windows

Can I install Ubuntu on a new laptop HDD. Can I then run programs like Adobe Photoshop for Windows 7 without having to install Windows. I have only ever been a Windows user and know nothing about Ubuntu. Any information on installing from 'scratch' would be helpful, and also is Ubuntu suitable for the casual user. How will the various drivers be affected?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I install Ubuntu on a new laptop HDD.

Yes, definitely. There are a lot of good and easy tutorials like this one:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

> Can I then run programs like Adobe Photoshop for Windows 7 without having to install Windows

That depends on the program itself. For many major programs, Linux/Ubuntu builds are available. Afaik Photoshop is not available yet, even though there are ways in which you can still run windows programs in ubuntu. Also, for every major program (office, photoshop, etc.) there's usually an feature-similar or even -equal open source version available for free (in this case you could use libre-/open-office and gimp/inkscape...).

> Any info on installing from 'scratch' would be helpful, and also is Ubuntu suitable for the casual user. How will the various Drivers be affected.

I'd recommend you read one of many transition guides like this one: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows

Comment: Hi BenSower. Thanks for your input, I will have a read of your suggestions.